# Connecting to an RT-B6 Sound System via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

The other day I was doing a disco and had issues connecting an RT-B6 Sound System I was using to a Windows 10 PC. The computer did connect but it played music  through the speakers instead of the sound system. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No pun intended but it *sounds* like you didn't change the output. *Some* software lets you pick what output you want. Typically though you can pick the *global* output from the mixer [image]

Or from manage audio devices

[image]

Assuming it was set up correctly, either option should fix it.